# How to reconfigure rails 4 to use mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, rails-activerecord

I want to configure my existing rails application to use mongoid instead of a sql database. Ideally, I would have used "rails new --skip-active-record name_here." How do I do this after I've already made an application? I haven't done anything with the model or database yet so there are no files that i created relating to the database aside from what was made when I created the rails project.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by manually removing references to ActiveRecord::Base in your model files and replace them by `include Mongoid::Document`

You might also need to comment every line starting by `config.active_record` in your environment configuration files.
You'll find these files in `/config/environments/`

Then you can use the `rails g mongoid:config` command to generate the `mongoid.yml` configuration file.

PS : When using `rake` you'll have to use `rake db:mongoid:*` commands.

EDIT:

Also remove require `rails/all`

You'll have to require each framework separately, for example :

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

The complete list of frameworks included in `rails/all` is here :

- active_record
- action_controller
- action_view
- action_mailer
- active_job
- rails/test_unit
- sprockets

You can also disable all migration check in `test/test_helper.rb`